# Three.js : Box3 from an object not in scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, bounding-box, gltf

I have a problem adding a Bounding Box from an object in a different module. Right now, it is working fine as long as I write everything in my main function, but as soon as I create my function in a different file, and import in in the main file, it's not working anymore.

The error code I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateWorldMatrix')
    at Box3.expandByObject (three.module.js:4934:10)
    at Box3.setFromObject (three.module.js:4852:15)
    at camCollision (camColliders.js:68:37)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (World.js:355:7)
```

camColliders.js being the file I'm trying to put the function in, and World.js my main file.

Here is the function :

```
function camCollision() {
      const camBB = new Box3().setFromObject(camSphereDetector);

      const boule1BB = new Box3().setFromObject(boule1Obj);
      boule1BB.name = 'first';
      const boule2BB = new Box3().setFromObject(boule2Obj);
      boule2BB.name = 'second';
      const boule3BB = new Box3().setFromObject(boule3Obj);
      boule3BB.name = 'third';

      const boulesBB = [boule1BB, boule2BB, boule3BB];

      boulesBB.forEach((bbs) => {
        if (bbs.intersectsBox(camBB)) {
          console.log('got it');
        }
      });
    }

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      camCollision();
    });
```

When I'm doing this in a separate file, i'm first importing the objects from another file and they are all Mesh.

I believe the problem is that I can't create the Bounding Boxes in a separate file, because it needs to be added to the scene first, and I'm only adding them in the scene in World.js. Yet, the error is leading me to line 68, the variable for 'boule1BB', which is weird because 'camBB' should have the problem first ?

Here is how I'm creating the Box3 (these are just copying some GLTF objects position and size, cause I can't manage to get a Box3 from it) :

```
const boule1Obj = new Mesh(
    new SphereGeometry(2, 32, 16),
    new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red', transparent: true, opacity: 0 }),
  );
  boule1Obj.position.set(10, -3.5, 0);
```

Then, I would like to know, if I got the problem right : is there a way to create a Box3 in a different js file, from an object that is not added to the scene yet (even if it should when the function is being called) ? With a different way than 'setFromObject' maybe ? Or am I not understanding the real problem.

For a bit of context, the aim is to provide some informations about each model when the user clicks on it, and I'm planning on putting the informations as '.name' for each Mesh corresponding to a model. So I don't want to write all this stuff in the main file, but rather on a separate one.

I hope this is clear enough, and I've given enough content for a solution to be found. I couldn't find anyone else having this problem. If you need anything else, please tell me !

Thanks already for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe the problem is that I can't create the Bounding Boxes in a separate file, because it needs to be added to the scene in World.js.

Not so.  Since a constructed `THREE.Mesh` has a shape with extents (from its geometry) and a transform (by default, translated to the origin, with no scaling or rotation), Three.js can and will determine a bounding box from that information as though the mesh were in the scene. I've posted a [demo](https://codepen.io/pnichols04/pen/YzEKzBq) of this on CodePen.

Nor should defining the object in one file and referencing it another make any difference, *as long as the object is in scope and initialized at the time it's bound to*.

Here, I suspect that you're assigning boule1Obj, boule2Obj, and boule3Obj in World.js.  In that case, the imported function is being hoisted before the variables are assigned, and the function is <s>seeing</s>**binding to** them as <s>unassigned</s>**`undefined`**.

Try changing `camCollision()` to accept the `bouleXObj`s as arguments.

```js
function camCollision(...objs) {
  const camBB = new Box3().setFromObject(camSphereDetector);

  for(let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    const objBB = new Box3().setFromGeometry(objs[i]);
    objBB.name = `Bounding Box ${i + 1}`;
    if(objBB.intersectsBox(camBB)) {
      console.log("Got it!");
    }
  }
}
```

And then call it as

```
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  camCollision(boule1Obj, boule2Obj, boule3Obj);
});
```

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks a lot for answering. I've jumped straight into three.js without any prior knowledge in Javascript, so that's why I'm missing a lot.

It works perfectly when I'm adding the function in my main function in World.js, before or after the eventListener, but still it doesn't when the function is written in a different file (blends.js, in which the objects are also created).

I've changed the 'setFromGeometry', to 'setFromObject', since the console was logging 'setFromGeometry' is not a function.

Maybe you need the complete file to spot what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks also for the demo. Indeed, the function is working right after importing the objects from the dedicated function, even when I'm not adding them into the scene. I think I got the problem : the object 'camSphereDetector' is attached to the camera with 'camera.add(camSphereDetector' in World.js, but it seems like when the collision function is in a different file it doesn't update this object's position ? I tried placing 'camSphereDetector' at the same position as a 'bouleXObj', and it works. I guess I need to find a way to update the sphere position before the function is being called.

Comment: Using `.add()`, `camShpereDetector`'s _local_ position is _always_ going to remain at (0, 0, 0).  _(This is somewhat oversimplified, but an object's position is_ local _and_ relative to its parent.  _For an object added to the scene, the parent is the scene, and the local position is the same as the object's world position.  For an object added to another object, the parent is that other object; the child's position (here, (0, 0, 0)) becomes a translation from the parent object's position, and its `.position` property isn't updated to reflect its (or the parent's) world position.)_

Comment: To overcome this, after the line `const camBB = new Box3()...`, add `camBB.translate(camSphereDetector.getWorldPosition(new Vector3());`.

Comment: The CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/pnichols04/pen/ExbYmBE) demonstrates the point.

Comment: I think I understand what you're explaining to me. So now, the problem is that the `camSphereDetector` stays at the initial camera position. I've animated it, the BoxHelper is moving the same way, and when I add the `camSphereDetector`to the `camera`, it successfully follows it. So I managed to have the Box following the sphere thanks to you, but it is the sphere that isn't moving. I tried to adapt the code you gave me with `getWorldPosition` of the camera, but it will log an error with the console.

So yea, I still can't manage to attach the sphere to the camera without `camera.add`.

Comment: Thanks also for the 2 examples, this is getting me closer to understanding how this really works.

Comment: You can still use `camera.add`; just use it in combination with `getWorldPosition`.  What's the error in the console?

Comment: Also, note that the `BoxHelper` I used in my second demo was just the fastest way of illustrating a bounding box.  All of the `...Helper` classes in Three.js exist to provide visual proxies for things that don't normally have visuals (bounding boxes, lights, axes, etc.).  You don't need it in your code.

Comment: Well I get a few.

When I add `camSphereDetector.translate(camera.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()));` I get the error `THREE.Object3D: .translate() has been removed. Use .translateOnAxis( axis, distance ) instead.`

And when I add the line in World.js, right after `camera.add(camSphereDetector` I get the same error, plus another one : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')
    at Vector3.copy (three.module.js:4090:14)
    at Mesh.translateOnAxis (three.module.js:7437:9)
    ...`.

Comment: But `camBB.translate(camSphereDetector.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()));` is not logging any error tho... Sorry for the multiple problems.

Comment: Also, if I set the camera position the same as a bouleXObj, and then set the camSphereDetector position to copy the camera position, it works. But as soon as I add `camBB.translate(camSphereDetector.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()));`, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241368/discussion-between-phil-n-and-s4ik).